# unable to understand space complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: python, data-structures, space-complexity

im unable to understand the space complexity of https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/solution/ question's solution.

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:

        intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

        merged = []
        for interval in intervals:
            # if the list of merged intervals is empty or if the current
            # interval does not overlap with the previous, simply append it.
            if not merged or merged[-1][1] < interval[0]:
                merged.append(interval)
            else:
            # otherwise, there is overlap, so we merge the current and previous
            # intervals.
                merged[-1][1] = max(merged[-1][1], interval[1])

        return merged
```

In 6th line merged = [] the data will be added to this list(depending upon the size of the given list in test cases). then why space complexity is said to be o(1) but not o(n). Im new to this.

Comment: `If we can sort intervals in place, we do not need more than constant additional space. Otherwise, we must allocate linear space to store a copy of intervals and sort that.` from the website you sent

Comment: @JoshuaNixon can u please explain me this why does this happen? arent we adding intervals to the merged list?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the explaination of the solution, you will see at the bottom that:

> Space complexity : O(1) or O(n)

This means that in the **best case** it will be `O(1)`, i.e. the case in which all the intervals merge into a single interval, For example,

```
intervals_list = [[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 8], [6, 10]]
```

All these can be merged into a single interval `[1, 10]`

So the space is constant in this case.

Now lets come to the **worst case** scenario, in which the space complexity will be `O(n)`

```
intervals_list = [[1, 3], [5, 8], [9, 11], [13, 17]]
```

None of these intervals can be merged hence the final result stored in `merged` will be exactly same as `intervals_list`, i.e. it will be the same size as the input, hence `O(n)` complexity.